# =IF(ISBLANK([Last Update]),"",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy")-[Last Update]) is retruning negative numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have the following formula inside a calculated column:-

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Last Update]),"",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy")-[Last Update])
```

but today is `27/08/2020`, and on some cases where the Last Update = `26/08/2020` the result of the above formula will be -1!! not sure what is going on?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use TODAY() instead of NOW()?

Comment: Use DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d"), see more at:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)

Comment: @Sandro this will cause the same issue but less frequent

Comment: @MatiurRahman can you advice more on this please?

Comment: This will also work: =IF(ISBLANK(RequestedDate),"",(TODAY()-RequestedDate)); Also the following worked for me: =IF(ISBLANK(RequestedDate),"",DATEDIF(RequestedDate,TODAY(),"d"))

Comment: @MatiurRahman this formula will return -1 for some values `=IF(ISBLANK(RequestedDate),"",(TODAY()-RequestedDate));` + this formula will return `#NUM!` for some items `=IF(ISBLANK(RequestedDate),"",DATEDIF(RequestedDate,TODAY(),"d")) `

Answer (score 1):

Per my test it works well using your syntax:

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(Date),"",NOW()-Date)
```

Please add a new calculated column named NowTime to check the result:

**NowTime Column:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF to calculate the difference between 2 dates in Number of Days as follow -

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Last Update]),"",DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Last Update],"d"))
```

Comment: your formula will return #NUM! for most of the fields..

Answer (score 0):

For **future** dates, the following returns #Name. I'm glad that you have made it to work in your own way.

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(DateOfEntry),"",DATEDIF(DateOfEntry,TODAY(),"d"))
```

[image]